# Why doesn't this revision show that anything was changed?

Tags: bug, revision-history

See revision 10 of this answer: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/152199/revisions

[image]

Neither of the other two buttons (Inline, Side-by-side Markdown) show anything either:

[image]

Revisions 11 and 12 are also showing nothing, those are where I tried rolling back to 9 then back to 10.

On Windows 10, reproducible in both Edge and Chrome, as well as iOS safari, iOS Chrome, and the iOS Reddit app's in-app browser.

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Comment: @Trish no it has not.

Answer (score 4):

Seems there are *two spaces* in the beginning of the last line (just before the word "Having") in revision #9. These spaces were removed in revision #10. [See diff online](https://www.diffchecker.com/w0ZyXGb1/): revision #9 is on the left, revision #10 on the right.

For posterity:

[The source of revision #9](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/997d9e04-e40a-4414-8afa-64bb8c95d2d2/view-source) ([direct edit link](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/152199/edit/997d9e04-e40a-4414-8afa-64bb8c95d2d2)) is:

```
## At the very least, using the metric of "Something is a target if and only if it is explicitly called a target" does not work ##

The PHB states (page 204):  
> A typical spell requires you to pick one or more targets to be affected by the spell’s magic. A spell’s description tells you whether the spell targets creatures, objects, or a point of origin for an area of effect...

If we wanted to only say a spell targets something if something it affects is explicitly called out as a "target" in the spell's description, we would run into a number of issues:    

Some touch spells never actually use the word "target" but instead use the word "creature" or "object".  These are spells are: 

 - *Cure Wounds*, *Darkvision*, *Spare the Dying*, *Jump*, *Beast Bond*, *Dragon's Breath*, *Beast Sense*, *Protection from Energy*, *Revivify*, *True Seeing*, *True Resurrection*, *Remove Curse*, and *Life Transference*.   

  Having these seemingly random spells not have targets would be a particularly odd decision.

In addition, all three instantaneous cylindrical spells (*conjure volley*, *ice storm* and *flame strike*) never mention targets in their descriptions.

Neither does every single AoE spell that is not instantaneous. 

The following spells also never mention having targets or that anything is considered a target:   

 - *Astral Projection*, *Beast Sense*, *Burning Hands*, *Feather Fall*, *Friends*, *Hellish Rebuke*, *Mass Healing Word*, *Meteor Swarm*, *Power Word Kill*, *Prayer of Healing*, *Shatter*, *Sunburst*, *Water Breathing*,
   *Word of Recall*, *Thunderclap*, *Word of Radiance*, *Sword Burst*, *Snilloc's Snowball Swarm*, *Thunder Step*, *Tidal Wave*, *Erupting Earth*, and *Abi-Dalzim's Horrid Wilting*.   

  
  Having all the above spells not have targets of any kind seems incredibly arbitrary and would mean that none of the above spells could be Twinned, War Cast, or put into a *glyph of warding*.
```

[The source of revision #10](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/997d9e04-e40a-4414-8afa-64bb8c95d2d2/view-source) ([direct edit link](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/152199/edit/9d81da1c-1e5a-4454-b7b3-03057923ad5a)) is:

```
## At the very least, using the metric of "Something is a target if and only if it is explicitly called a target" does not work ##

The PHB states (page 204):  
> A typical spell requires you to pick one or more targets to be affected by the spell’s magic. A spell’s description tells you whether the spell targets creatures, objects, or a point of origin for an area of effect...

If we wanted to only say a spell targets something if something it affects is explicitly called out as a "target" in the spell's description, we would run into a number of issues:    

Some touch spells never actually use the word "target" but instead use the word "creature" or "object".  These are spells are: 

 - *Cure Wounds*, *Darkvision*, *Spare the Dying*, *Jump*, *Beast Bond*, *Dragon's Breath*, *Beast Sense*, *Protection from Energy*, *Revivify*, *True Seeing*, *True Resurrection*, *Remove Curse*, and *Life Transference*.   

  Having these seemingly random spells not have targets would be a particularly odd decision.

In addition, all three instantaneous cylindrical spells (*conjure volley*, *ice storm* and *flame strike*) never mention targets in their descriptions.

Neither does every single AoE spell that is not instantaneous. 

The following spells also never mention having targets or that anything is considered a target:   

 - *Astral Projection*, *Beast Sense*, *Burning Hands*, *Feather Fall*, *Friends*, *Hellish Rebuke*, *Mass Healing Word*, *Meteor Swarm*, *Power Word Kill*, *Prayer of Healing*, *Shatter*, *Sunburst*, *Water Breathing*,
   *Word of Recall*, *Thunderclap*, *Word of Radiance*, *Sword Burst*, *Snilloc's Snowball Swarm*, *Thunder Step*, *Tidal Wave*, *Erupting Earth*, and *Abi-Dalzim's Horrid Wilting*.   

  
Having all the above spells not have targets of any kind seems incredibly arbitrary and would mean that none of the above spells could be Twinned, War Cast, or put into a *glyph of warding*.
```

---

As for why those do not show up on the site - I suspect it is a bug where the whitespace is trimmed or otherwise manipulated.

Comment: I believe that for whatever reason, when there's no difference in the rendered post (i.e. no change shown under "Inline" or "Side-by-side"), it causes nothing to be shown in the "Side-by-side Markdown" tab either. ...I'm pretty sure there's an MSE post reporting this somewhere, but I can't find it.

Comment: @V2Blast yeah, sounds likely. I tried sciencing it by introducing extactly the same whitespace between the second to last and the last paragraph in some of my posts. However, the edit did show up. [Example](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/139015/revisions). It must be a more complex series of steps needed to get into that situation.

Comment: I'm guessing this bug was fixed at some point; revisions 10-12 from the revision history linked in the question above now seem to display properly.